# how to drag circle from one container to another container in flex project

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am creating an flex Air project,so mxml file will run.
I have circles in one Big circle at one side and will be same on other side.

Now how to drag any circle from any Big circle to other side. Or it could be like any two container having circles, then how to drag and drop circle?

For one circle i am able to do drag and drop.But I want one Big circle on left hand side and one big circle on right hand side .And small circles with class names will be in these big circles.Now i want to drag and drop those small circles in big circles.Big cicles should not move.Please help me. Even i have tried this code in actionscript

```
    package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.engine.GroupElement;

    public class lastWork extends Sprite
    {
        public function lastWork()
        {
            drawBigCircles(200,100,100);
            drawBigCircles(400,280,100);
        drawCircles(190,90,15);
        drawCircles(180,130,15);
        drawCircles(150,70,15);
        drawCircles(400,240,20);

        }
        public function drawBigCircles(x:Number,y:Number,radius:Number):void{
            var circle:Sprite=new Sprite();
            circle.graphics.beginFill(0xFFCC00,1);
            circle.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x666666);


            circle.graphics.drawCircle(x,y,radius);
            this.addChild(circle);
            addChild(circle);
        }
        public function drawCircles(x:Number,y:Number,radius:Number):void
        {
            var group:GroupElement =new GroupElement();

            var circle:Sprite=new Sprite();
            circle.graphics.beginFill(0xFFCC00,1);
            circle.graphics.lineStyle(1,0x666666);


            circle.graphics.drawCircle(x,y,radius);
            this.addChild(circle);
            addChild(circle);
            circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown) 

            function mouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                circle.startDrag();
            }
            circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseReleased);

            function mouseReleased(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                circle.stopDrag();
                trace(circle.dropTarget.name);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But in this i want big circles should not move and small circles should only be dragged.If you can also tell me how to put any text in these small circles.Small circle with text in it should be drag and dropped to other big circle.

Comment: for one cicle i am able to do drag and drop.But I want one Big circle on left hand side and one big circle on right hand side .And small circles with class names will be in these big circles.Now i want to drag and drop those small circles in big circles.Big cicles should not move.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with 2 Containers? Just create a custom component and drag  circles inside it (the code below even works in a mobile Flex project with a View):

[image: enter code here]

MyApp.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    xmlns:comps="*">
    <comps:MyCircle width="100%" height="100%"/>
</s:Application>
```

MyCircle.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:UIComponent 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    width="100%" height="100%">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.filters.*;

            public static const SHADOW:Array = [ new DropShadowFilter(10, 80, 0x000000, 0.5, 32, 32, 1, 1, false, false, false) ];
            private var dX:Number, dY:Number;
            private var circle:Shape = new Shape();

            override protected function createChildren():void {
                super.createChildren();

                circle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
                circle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 20);
                addChild(circle);

                addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleDown);
            }

            override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
                super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

                circle.x = unscaledWidth / 2;
                circle.y = unscaledHeight / 2;
            }

            private function handleDown(event:MouseEvent):void {
                dX = circle.x - stage.mouseX;
                dY = circle.y - stage.mouseY;
                circle.scaleX = circle.scaleY = 1.5;
                circle.filters = SHADOW;
                //startDrag();
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleDrag);
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleUp);
            }

            private function handleDrag(event:MouseEvent):void {
                circle.x = stage.mouseX + dX;
                circle.y = stage.mouseY + dY;
                event.updateAfterEvent();
            }

            private function handleUp(event:MouseEvent):void {
                circle.filters = null;
                circle.scaleX = circle.scaleY = 1;
                //stopDrag();
                stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleDrag);
                stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleUp);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</mx:UIComponent>
```